# How to run multiple scenarios other than using tags in Karate?

Tags: java, karate, gherkin

I am trying to add a functionality in my stack where I would only run specific scenarios which path and line are stored in my database. These scenarios would be injected to the `TestRunner` file.

```
  @Test
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void testParallel() {
    Assertions.assertThat(Runtime.version().feature())
        .as("Java version should be 11").isEqualTo(11);

    // Pretend this getting scenarios from DB
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    paths.add("src/test/java/feature/test.feature:4");
    paths.add("src/test/java/feature/test.feature:12");

    Builder runnerBuilder = new Builder();
    runnerBuilder.path(paths);
    runnerBuilder.outputCucumberJson(true);
    runnerBuilder.outputJunitXml(true);
    runnerBuilder.hooks(getKarateHooks());
    Results results = runnerBuilder.parallel(1);

    ...
  }
```

When I run this, there's no scenarios executed at all. But when I feed the list with just one scenario path it can run that one scenario. Not sure what's wrong with it. The `path` method can accept either a string or a list. So I would assume this is how you run multiple scenarios with path. But I got no luck.

These are the `path` methods in `Runner.class` in `karate-core`:

```
    public T path(String... value) {
      this.path(Arrays.asList(value));
      return this;
    }

    public T path(List<String> value) {
      if (value != null) {
        if (this.paths == null) {
          this.paths = new ArrayList();
        }

        this.paths.addAll(value);
      }

      return this;
    }
```

Comment: as far as I know - a list of paths is supposed to work. this is not a high priority for the oss project, so I suggest you dive into the code (it is all open source) and contribute a PR. if you need enterprise support, use the contact form using your official email: https://www.karatelabs.io/support

Comment: @PeterThomas thank you for your reply. Upon looking into the code, I found out that the method `findFeatureFiles` in `ResourceUtils` only handles 1 path and there's a TODO comment for handling multiple paths. I think that answers why 0 scenario run when I added multiple paths.